# How do I change the Android Manifest to launch an Application instead of an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I would like my program to extend the Application class to and launch from it's Overridden onCreate() method, rather than from an Activity class. How do I change the manifest to launch an application?

I only know how to launch activities like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How can I tell Android that it needs to launch from an Application instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check the use of [Application Class](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-application-class.html)

```
Application class is used to declare Global variables and other stuffs but it doesn't have any UI.
```

To declare `Application` class you just need to add `android:name` `attribute` in your application tag in the `AndroidManifest` file

`<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".myApplication_class_name">`

Comment: This is actually what I was looking to do. Declare variables and stuffs in the Application class and then launch the Activity from there. I keep forgetting how android is completely event-driven. (New to android dev.) Thanks lots!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Android does not work this way. Activities are a main UI component. If you want to show UI to user you must use activities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components